# Disable ability of web pages to turn off my context menu in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript

I want to disable the ability of a web site to to turn off my context menu in IE.  I do not want to turn off javascript entirely, I just want to prevent javascript code from intercepting the right click event.  Firefox lets you do this with a checkbox in the user preferences dialog.  I can't find an equivalent in IE. I am currently using IE8.

Comment: [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) also provides this option (_right-click_ on the web page -> "_Edit Site Preferences..._" menu option -> "_Scripting_" tab -> "_Allow scripts to detect context menu events_" checkbox {enabled by default}).

Comment: maxthon2 which uses the IE engine has a plugin for rightclick enable. You gotta figure if they were intent on keeping the user controlled, it would actually work on something :-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any setting or registry tweak that can do this, however you may be able to re-enable the context menu on a page-by-page basis by entering this into your address bar:

> javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null)

You can create a bookmark with this as the URL to make it easier to use.

This should work on most sites that disable the context menu. Until and unless a setting becomes available in IE, though, your best bet (and not only for this particular issue but for browsing in general) would be to use a different browser.

Comment: I don't use IE except at work to access some enterprise web apps that seem to go out of their way to only work on IE.  I was trying to debug an issue with one and realized how spoiled I am by firefox and chrome.  I really wish our bean counters would specify something like "must work in at least one non ie browser" when they put out software RFP's.

Comment: Also, the javascript snippet you posted is helpful in many cases, but it doesn't work on the particular page that made me annoyed enough to post this question :)

Comment: @Peter Been there. There's an application my company uses which is an ActiveX Control based web app. It requires a 32 bit version of IE6 to run, and must be run with Admin rights. Luckily, I don't have to use it much.

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and trying to view the source of some enterprise web-app with a custom context menu in a pop-up window with no location bar, no status bar, and no menu bar don't panic. You can get to everything you need just by pressing F12 and bringing up the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is for IE8, but for people like me, coming to look for IE9 at least, Shift+Right click seems to work. Try it in IE8 and let us know.